# How to send focus to control with tabindex lower than current control in C# windows form application?

Tags: c#, .net

In My C# Windows Form Application I have many TextBox Controls in a Form in which user enter data to be saved in a database.I want user to be able to change focus to each of these TextBoxes through Up and Down arrows.I could do that for the down arrow so when user press down arrow the focus is set to the textbox with higher tabindex through SendKey("Tab"). BUT i couldn't do that for the UP arrow so when user press up arrow focus is set to the textbox with lower tabindex , Any help please ??

Comment: would you please post the code that changes the focus for the **down arrow (working)** and the code for the **up arrow (not working)**. We can then try to figure out *why* the latter isn't working

Comment: If you can do it for the down arrow you should be able to do it with the up arrow.. sounds like you will have to set individually all the tab indexes correctly.. also if I remember correctly.. C# GUI acts funny when you drop / assign tab Indexes for controls not in order.. or maybe it's ASP.NET app i had a similar issue.. however show what code / key events you are trying to capture this on

Comment: This won't help, but using UP/DOWN to change focus is generally not a good idea. For example, UP/DOWN act as LEFT/RIGHT for single-line textboxes, so I do not recommend changing the behavior to act as a TAB.

Comment: Check my answer, I just tested it.

Comment: It already works this way, don't help.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Instead of using SendKey() you can use `Control.SelectNextControl()` , and use `forward=false` to go backwards.

Answer (score 5):

Can you try something like `SendKeys.Send("+{TAB}");` which would emulate a Shift Key + Tab so should take you back

Answer (score 4):

The best way to move between Textboxs is to use 
Control.SelectNextControl + forward parameter.

Check the code below,Each time the user press key down on the form, the next control is activated:

```
private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        Control ctl;
        ctl = (Control)sender;
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Down )
        {
            ctl.SelectNextControl(ActiveControl, true, true, true, true);
        }
        else if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Up)
        {
            ctl.SelectNextControl(ActiveControl, false, true, true, true);
        }
    }
```

Don't forgot to set keypreview for the form to true.

Comment: Just a note: to use this Form's `KeyPress` must be set to `true` :)

Answer (score 2):

You can send a Shift+Tab, consult the documentation about how to do this with SendKeys

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.sendkeys.aspx